# How to check if a Node server is up from Android JNI in C code

Tags: android, node.js, c, react-native, server

I have been trying to check if a **NodeJs** Server is up from **C** code in **Android JNI**, but my attempt never returns true even when the server is up, even when I can connect to the server from the app.

**Here's my approach in C :**

```
const char *myIpAddress = "192.168.0.13";
int count = 10;
struct in_addr ip_bin;

int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sock < 0) {
  return my_call_back_func("0");;
}

struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
q    server_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT_NO);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_pton(AF_INET, myIpAddress, &ip_bin);

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "MyApp", "Binary representation of %s: %x\n", myIpAddress, ntohl(ip_bin.s_addr));

int i;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "MyApp", "\n>>> %d PING <<<", i);

  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) >= 0) {
    close(sock);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN, "MyApp", "\n>>> IP connection successful !!! <<<");
    my_call_back_func("1");

    return;
  }

  close(sock);
  usleep(PING_SLEEP_RATE);
}
```

**NodeJs Server :**

```
const MY_PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const MY_HOST = "192.168.0.13";
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.on("listening", function () {
    console.log(`>>> R.D Server is running ${JSON.stringify(server.address())}`);
});

server.listen(MY_PORT, MY_HOST, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${MY_PORT} . . . .`);
    console.log(`CORS-enabled web server listening on port : ${MY_PORT}`);
});
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: *"but my attempt never returns true.*" ---> Why do you mean by this?

Comment: It never *recognizes* that the server is up